# Sending information across pages PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

i have an ajax / php feature of my site that pulls in information from a table every 20 seconds. The information is about hobbie's

It displays on the page the name of the person and their hobby. I have a second page that acts as an information source for that hobby. Currently the only way to access the second page is by entering your hobby into a form on the first page. How would i get it so that i could click on the hobby that is being displayed on the homepage and access an information page on the hobby.

To access the information it currently grabs the hobby from a POST command.

The table results are being displayed on the homepage via

```
echo $row['name']." is interested in ".$row['hobby'];
```

Could i some how pass the hobby name through to another page? I only know how to do it through form submits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that sesssions are necessary for this.

Look at what information your form is sending.  If you're making a GET request you can add that url to a link.

So on your home page you could have links like the one below instead of forms.

`<a href="/hobbies/?name=remote+controlled+cars>Remote Controlled Cars</a>`

So with the link it would no longer be using `$_POST` but `$_GET` instead.

Psudeo code for your homepage link below.
`<a href="/hobbies/?name=<?php echo slugify($row['hobby']); ?>><?php echo $row['hobby']; ?></a>`

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.  I misread the OP and sessions are likely overkill.

Comment: Either of our answers would work; mine conforms to the OP's current skill level, while yours would have them make a small leap in learning HTML- a small obstacle in the scheme of things.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using PHP's [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anchor tag that is generated from the data provided with a query tailing it to carry the data over, effectively creating a link pointing to the next step with additional information. The only problem, of course, is that this is exposed to the user which can be hijacked.

You can also, if you are using *only* form submits, create a `<input type="hidden">` with a value/name of something you can use to navigate to the next page, if you so desire.